# Deriving Continuum BdG equation from Tight-Binding model for Graphene-Superconductor interface

Tags: fourier-transform, superconductivity, graphene, tight-binding

## Background

My question concerns Beenakker's paper on "Specular Andreev Reflection in Graphene": [cond-mat/0604594](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0604594) (arxiv)/[Phys.Rev.Lett. **97**, 067007](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.97.067007) (The same topic is also discussed in [Rev. Mod. Phys. **80**, 1337](https://doi.org/10.1103/RevModPhys.80.1337))

In this paper the conductance is calculated for a N-S interface using the Blonder-Tinkham-Klapwijk formalism. The starting point is the BdG equation
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
H-E_F & \Delta\\
\Delta^* & E_F - THT^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
u\\
v
\end{bmatrix} = \epsilon\begin{bmatrix}
u\\
v
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}
$E_F,\Delta$, and $\epsilon$ is the Fermi energy, superconducting gap, and excitation energy respectively. For simplicity neglect the proximity effect such that we can use a step-potential $\Delta = \Delta_0 \theta(x)$. $u$ and $v$ are electron and hole components.
Here $H$ is the single-particle Hamiltonian in a hexagonal lattice (graphene)
\begin{equation}
H = \begin{bmatrix}
H_+ & 0 \\
0 & H_-
\end{bmatrix},
\end{equation}
with
\begin{equation}
H_{\pm} = -i \hbar v \left(\sigma_x \partial_x \pm \sigma_y \partial_y\right).
\end{equation}
In this notation $v$ and $\sigma_{x,y}$are the Fermi velocity, and Pauli matrices respectively.

## The problem

It is easy to derive this equation by starting from a nearest neighbour Tight-binding Hamiltonian of the form
\begin{equation}
H = - t \sum_{\langle ij \rangle} c_i^{\dagger} c_j - E_F \sum_i c_i^{\dagger} c_i + \sum_{i \sigma}\left(\sigma \Delta c_{i,\sigma}^{\dagger} c_{i,-\sigma}^{\dagger} + h.c.\right)
\end{equation}
as done here cond-mat/1308.0017 (arxiv). It is assumed that the lattice is hexagonal with two sublattices A and B. In order to do so one assumes translational invariance in both the $x$ and $y$ directions and performs the usual Fourier transformations
\begin{equation}
A_{\mathbf{k} \sigma} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N_A}}\sum_i A_{i \sigma} e^{-i \mathbf{k}\cdot \mathbf{r}}.
\end{equation}
Here $A (B)$ denotes operators living on the A (B) sublattice. One also has to perform the replacement $\mathbf{p} = - i \hbar \nabla$, and double the degrees of freedom (but these steps are not important for my question).

However, I'm not sure if this method is rigorous (although it seems it is extensively used in the literature). My issue is that to perform the Fourier transformation I thought it was necessary to assume translational invariance in the $x$ direction. However, this symmetry is broken by the $\Delta = \Delta_0 \theta(x)$ term. For simplicity we assume that $t$ and $E_F$ are constants.

- Are there any assumptions that validate ignoring the broken translational symmetry?
- If not is there perhaps a better way to re-derive the BdG equation starting from the Tight-binding model?

Comment: For the BdG model, the absolute fluctuations in the number of particles increase without bound when going towards the thermodynamic limit of $N\to \infty$, but the relative fluctuations vanish. The superconducting state can only exist because of unbounded fluctuations in the number of particles, but the fluctuations are still negligible compared to the total number of particles, and in practice not easily observable. Thus, you can ignore the broken symmetry.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand why this means that we can ignore the broken symmetry. Can you elaborate? Your comment is close to a satisfactory answer